# 0x Overbuying buyToken when setting slippagePercentage > 0

Tags: 0x

Based on the documentation here: https://0x.org/docs/api#request-1, I expected the 0xApi to obtain the exact amount of `buyToken` specified in the request, while applying the "slippageTolerance" to the `sellAmount`.

However the api / router seems to buy overbuy the buyToken returning roughly `(1+slippagePercentage)*buyAmount` instead of the actual specified amount.

Did I misunderstand the documentation or is this an error in the api / router ?

To reproduce you can run this test against a local mainnet fork :
https://github.com/ckoopmann/0xApiExperiments/blob/main/test/index.ts

Which resulted in the following output for me (note that the api was queried for a fixed `buyAmount` of 100 sushi tokens with 5% slippage and ended up buying slightly more than 105 tokens:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `buyAmount` in 0xAPI, the `buyAmount` is guaranteed as a minimum. Not all underlying liquidity sources provide `buyExact` functionality so buys are converted to sells.

The settlement will revert if `boughtAmount < buyAmount`. So it is often the case that when using `buyAmount` the trader buys more than expected.